# How can I compute the duration for a UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut animation with a known starting velocity and distance?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, animation, core-animation, easing-functions

I'm animating a view between two points using UIViewAnimationCurveLinear, so I know the velocity of this animation.  In certain circumstances I want to append a UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut to make the view slow to a stop.  To make this effect seamless, the ease-out animation must start at the same velocity as the linear animation that preceded it.  Given a fixed distance over which I want this easing to occur, how can I compute the duration necessary to achieve this known starting velocity?

For example, let's say I'm animating my view from x = 0 to x = 100 over 10 seconds.  The velocity is therefore 10 pixels / second.  I now want the view to decelerate from x = 100 to x = 120 using a UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut animation.  What duration should this animation be to ensure that it starts at 10 pixels / second?

It's my understanding that Core Animation's CAMediaTimingFunction controls animation pacing using cubic Bezier curves, where the second and third control points dictate the shape of the curve.  I presume that the UIViewAnimationCurve easing functions are also cubic Bezier curves.  If I knew the default control points used by these functions I should be able to work out the formula to compute duration given velocity and distance, but I haven't managed to find these default control points documented anywhere.

Comment: Why not just use EaseOut over the whole animation?

Answer (score 1):

I might not be able to give you a complete answer, but I can point you towards the CAMediaTimingFunction's -getControlPointAtIndex:values: method.  That should let you create an EaseOut timing function and then examine it's control points.

I'll also point you towards an [article by Matt Gallagher](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/09/parametric-acceleration-curves-in-core.html) about custom acceleration curves done using CAKeyframeAnimation which might also be of use to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a constant (call it `BEZIER_INTEGRAL_CONSTANT`) that approximates the integral of the Bezier curve for an animation that is 1 second long starting at a velocity of 1 pixel / second. For linear easing, this constant is `0.5`. For `UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut`, it is *approximately* `0.7`. The formula in terms of the duration is:

```
duration = distance / (velocity * BEZIER_INTEGRAL_CONSTANT)
```

For your example, where the distance is 20 pixels and the starting velocity is 10 pixels / second, the duration should be approximately: `20 / (10 * 0.7) = 2.9 seconds`.